# Can't change the background color of windows which are inside another window

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to change the background color of a STATIC window, both - on load and change it on runtime. So far I have been able to change the color the following way:

```
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(200, 200, 20));
        SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(10, 10, 10));
        SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
        return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(30, 30, 30));
    }
```

Everything works fine and the background color gets changed, except for any STATIC windows, which are inside another static window:

```
HWND mainContainer = CreateWindowEx
(
    0,
    _TEXT("STATIC"),
    "",
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_SOLID,
    10, 10, 500, 500,
    hwnd,
    NULL,
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
    NULL
);

HWND subItem = CreateWindowEx
(
    0,
    _TEXT("STATIC"),
    "SubItem",
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_SOLID,
    10, 10, 100, 100,
    mainContainer,
    NULL,
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(mainContainer, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
    NULL
);
```

In this case the mainContainer color gets changed, but not the background color for subItem. Any ideas why this is happening? Thank you!

Comment: Since the outer static is not marked `CLIPCHILDREN`, it is allowed to draw on top of its children, which includes erasing the background to a different color. (Note also that returning a `CreateSolidBrush` is a memory leak since nobody destroys that brush.)

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for the reply! My dwStyle has been set to "WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN" for the parentContainer, but still the same problem persists. Any more hints please? Thanks!

Comment: Remember that the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message it sent to the static control's parent. In this case, `subitem` will send it to `mainContainer`. Are you handling the message in `mainContainer`'s window procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` will be sent only to the parent window, but not parent's parent window.

According to [About Static Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/Controls/about-static-controls) :

> The window procedure for the predefined static control window class
>   performs default processing for all messages that the static control
>   procedure does not process.

The `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is not in the list that it process. So The predefined window procedure will passes the message to DefWindowProc for default processing.

(We really don't often put a static window inside another static window. This is not a common operation. So you should reset the parent window of `subItem` to `hwnd`.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you please tell me if I wanted to add scrollbar to the container, should I simply use scrollbar control without any container and handle the "cropping" manually? Thanks!

Comment: Add the `WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL` to `dwStyle`?